# Mac Bluetooth takes too long to show devices

Tags: mac, bluetooth

There is a device waiting to be paired up, but it's been more than 5 minutes minutes and the loading blinker on the top right is still looping.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it all BT devices or just a specific device?  Have you tried an SMC reset or deleting the BT plist?

Comment: @fsb Those would all make a great answer on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: BT pairing only lasts about a minute. If you’ve gone more than that, there’s an issue. Can you pair that device to another computer?  Do you have other BT devices you can try to pair with this Mac?